# Removing black background from the raster which has actual data pixels with value 0 in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, nodata, background

I have a raster with the area of interest and a black background around it. The problem is I can't remove that area by putting 0 as additional nodata, since it's a DEM layer which has 0m elevations as actual data within the raster. I was wondering if there's another way to do it.

Comment: Add an alpha band or a mask band to define the nodata area. Do you have the area of valid data as a polygon?

Comment: @BERA Welp yes, I had written it in a version of the question before that I couldn't submit because of network issues, then I promptly forgot to add QGIS in the question later.

Comment: Ideally speaking, you shouldn't have 0 as Nodata value, and regions which have 0 as the value.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe It's a DEM layer with no decimal places (SRTM data downloaded from Google Earth Engine), how can I avoid this without taking out sea-level areas?